# adding a script tag to the DOM with javascript in IE with data attribute`

Tags: javascript, dom, requirejs

I need to add the following script tag to the DOM after a few things run on my page:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="lib/Require/require.js"></script>
```

I know that optimally everything will be in my require file, but as of now i need to hotfix this to work in IE.

What i have that is working in FF/Chrome is:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('data-main', 'js/main');
script.src = 'lib/Require/require.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChihld(script);
```

However, IE doesn't like it when i try to set the attribute `'data-main'` and therefore is not working.

How can i get around this and have it add the script element to the dom and have it load the script at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Probably it's just the transcription in here, but you have an extra `h` in `appendChihld`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

this seems to work fine in IE as well:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "lib/Require/require.js";
scriptTag.setAttribute("data-main", "js/main");
( document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement ).appendChild( scriptTag );
```

Comment: 'text/javascript' seems to be the problem. Thanks!